# SQL - Adding an avg column to a detail table

Tags: sql, average, teradata

I'm on Teradata. I have an order table like the below.

```
 custID | orderID | month | order_amount
-----------------------------------------
    1   |    1    |  jan  |      10
    1   |    2    |  jan  |      20
    1   |    3    |  feb  |       5
    1   |    4    |  feb  |       7
    2   |    5    |  mar  |      20
    2   |    6    |  apr  |      30
```

I'd like to add a column to the above table called "Avg order amount per month per customer". Since the table is at an order level, adding this column will cause duplicates like the below, which is ok.

```
 custID | orderID | month | order_amount | avgOrdAmtperMonth
-------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |    1    |  jan  |      10      |       15
    1   |    2    |  jan  |      20      |       15
    1   |    3    |  feb  |       5      |        6
    1   |    4    |  feb  |       7      |        6
    2   |    5    |  mar  |      20      |       20
    2   |    6    |  apr  |      30      |       30
```

I want the output to have all the columns above, not just the custid and the new column. I'm not sure how to write this because one part of the table is an at order level and the new column needs to be grouped by customer+month. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple *group average*:

```
AVG(order_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY custID, month)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do the calculation when you query the table?

```
select t.*,
       avg(order_amount) over (partition by custId, month) as avgOrderAmtPerMonth
from t;
```

You can add this into a view if you want to make it available to multiple downstream queries.

Actually adding the column to the table is a maintenance "nightmare".  You have to add triggers to the table and update the value for updates, inserts, and deletes.

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution.